# Find the indices of elements greater than x

Tags: python, indexing, logical-operators, indices

Given the following vector,

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

I need to identify the indices of "a" whose elements are >= than 4, like this:

```
idx = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

The info in "idx" will be used to delete the elements from another list X (X has the same number of elements that "a"):

```
del X[idx] #idx is used to delete these elements in X. But so far isn't working.
```

I heard that numpy might help. Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: loops are a good place to start.

Comment: Your `idx` example is wrong, there are only **9 elements** in the list, and therefore **9 indices, 0-8**.

Comment: Your question is slightly contradicting with itself. Looks like you might have confused indices with elements(Your `idx` in fact is list of elements and you are asking list of indices). Also please tell what have you tried on your own before asking?

Comment: @0xc0de I think he/she just type the pesudo code here .

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. Actually I failed to mention that I need to use idx as an index to remove the elements from another list, other than a...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

OK, I understand what you mean and a Single line of Python will be enough:

**using list comprehension**

```
[ j for (i,j) in zip(a,x) if i >= 4 ]
# a will be the list compare to 4
# x another list with same length

Explanation:
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> x
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j']
```

Zip function will return a list of tuples

```
>>> zip(a,x)
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (4, 'd'), (5, 'e'), (6, 'f'), (7, 'g'), (8, 'h'), (9, 'j')]
```

List comprehension is a shortcut to loop an element over list which after "in", and evaluate the element with expression, then return the result to a list, also you can add condition on which result you want to return

```
>>> [expression(element) for **element** in **list** if condition ]
```

This code does nothing but return all pairs that zipped up.

```
>>> [(i,j) for (i,j) in zip(a,x)]
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (4, 'd'), (5, 'e'), (6, 'f'), (7, 'g'), (8, 'h'), (9, 'j')]
```

What we do is to add a condition on it by specify "if" follow by a boolean expression

```
>>> [(i,j) for (i,j) in zip(a,x) if i >= 4]
[(4, 'd'), (5, 'e'), (6, 'f'), (7, 'g'), (8, 'h'), (9, 'j')]
```

**using Itertools**

```
>>> [ _ for _ in itertools.compress(d, map(lambda x: x>=4,a)) ]
# a will be the list compare to 4
# d another list with same length
```

Use itertools.compress with **single line** in Python to finish close this task

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> d = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j'] # another list with same length
>>> map(lambda x: x>=4, a)  # this will return a boolean list 
[False, False, False, True, True, True, True, True, True]


>>> import itertools
>>> itertools.compress(d, map(lambda x: x>4, a)) # magic here !
<itertools.compress object at 0xa1a764c>     # compress will match pair from list a and the boolean list, if item in boolean list is true, then item in list a will be remain ,else will be dropped
#below single line is enough to solve your problem
>>> [ _ for _ in itertools.compress(d, map(lambda x: x>=4,a)) ] # iterate the result.
['d', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j']
```

Explanation for itertools.compress, I think this will be clear for your understanding:

```
>>> [ _ for _ in itertools.compress([1,2,3,4,5],[False,True,True,False,True]) ]
[2, 3, 5]
```

Comment: @OliverAmundsen this will be my final solution

Comment: that worked! Thanks @ShawnZhang. Could briefly explain the logic of the "using list comprehension"? thx

Answer (score 46):

```
>>> [i for i,v in enumerate(a) if v > 4]
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

`enumerate` returns the index and value of each item in an array. So if the value `v` is greater than `4`, include the index `i` in the new array.

Or you can just modify your list in place and exclude all values above `4`.

```
>>> a[:] = [x for x in a if x<=4]
>>> a 
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 9):

The simplest in my eyes would be to use numpy

```
X[np.array(a)>4]#X needs to be np.array as well
```

Explanation:
np.array converts a to an array.

np.array(a)>4 gives a bool array with all the elements that should be kept

And X is filtered by the bool array so only the elements where a is greater than 4 are selected (and the rest discarded)

Answer (score 8):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array(range(1,10))
>>> indices = [i for i,v in enumerate(a >= 4) if v]
>>> indices
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

>>> mask = a >= 4
>>> mask
array([False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=boo
l)
>>> a[mask]
array([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> np.setdiff1d(a,a[mask])
array([1, 2, 3])
```

Answer (score 8):

I guess I came here a bit late (while things got easier using Numpy)..

```
import numpy as np

# Create your array
a = np.arange(1, 10)
# a = array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

# Get the indexes/indices of elements greater than 4 
idx = np.where(a > 4)[0]
# idx = array([4, 5, 6, 7, 8])

# Get the elements of the array that are greater than 4
elts = a[a > 4]
# elts = array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

# Convert idx(or elts) to a list
idx = list(idx)
#idx = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

using filter built-in function is fine

```
>>>a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>>filter(lambda x : x < 4, a)
[1, 2, 3]
```

**Explanation**

filter(FUN, Iterable)

this expression will iterate all element from Iterable and supply to FUN function as argument, if return is True ,then the arugment will be append to a internal list

lambda x: x > 4

this means a anonymous function that will take a argument and test it if bigger than 4, and return True of False value

**Your solution**

if you are try to delete all elements larger than 4 ,then try blow

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> filter(lambda x: x<4 ,a)
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: And what happens when you call `del a[9]`?

Comment: -1. You are returning list elements, not the indices. Although this works for the given list but it's not a correct answer.

Comment: @Aesthete length of a here is 9, a[9] means the 10th element of list.if del a[9], python will throw an index error

Comment: @0xc0de hi,nice for your rigourism. but as context from the question , index return will be used to delete element in the list . I think what I written will be helpful and show pythonic way to close the ticket.

Comment: @ShawnZhang: True. I think the question needs correction. Please edit your answer to reflect difference between what you think the questioner needs and what he is asking for so that I will cancel my -1 :).

Comment: @OliverAmundsen , I understand what you need and post another answer below ,using itertools.compress function .

Comment: @OliverAmundsen I've finalize my solution with list comprehension and itertools , you can just pick whichever you like .

Answer (score 0):

looping is slow, using divide and conquer method. code in C++

```
// find index whose value is equal to or greater than "key" in an ordered vector.
// note: index may be equal to indices.size()
size_t StartIndex(const std::vector<int>& indices, int key)
{
    if (indices.empty() || key <= indices[0])
        return 0;

    if (key > indices.back())
        return indices.size();

    size_t st = 0;
    size_t end = indices.size() - 1;

    while (true)
    {
        if ((end - st) < 2)
            return (indices[st] < key) ? end : st;

        size_t mid = ((st + end) >> 1);  // (st + end) / 2

        if (indices[mid] == key)
            return mid;

        (indices[mid] < key ? st : end) = mid;
    }
}
```